# iptables rule that allows to connect to ssh from the outside with mac validation

Tags: ssh, iptables

I try to connect **from outside my network** to my ssh server, but I want to restrict this connection only to my mac address

this rule work:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

However none of this rules work for me:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source 2c:fd:a1:zz:xx:yy -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source 2c:fd:a1:zz:xx:yy -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 2c:fd:a1:zz:xx:yy -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source 2c:fd:a1:zz:xx:yy -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

What should I do to protect ssh by mac validation?

PD: I know that SSH is a TCP/IP protocol, and only listen to an IP address, not a mac address, but I have read in some forums that it is possible to do it, but they do not explain the way. I also know that there are other ways to protect ssh, such as "port knocking", "keys instead of password", etc, etc., and that macs addresses can be falsified. But still I want to know how i can validate the entry by ssh using mac validation

Comment: Use the nat table for network address translation, not the mangle table.

Comment: @111 update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server/device can see only mac addresses of other devices in local network, but not devices behind a router.

So if one device can directly connect another - they see macs of each other.
But if one device should go through a router to connect another device (not switch or wifi switch, but router facing your two devices using different network interfaces), they cannot see macs of each other.

***a) In this case devices can see macs of each other***

```
(device1) <---\
                ----- (switch or wifi point)
(device2) <---/
```

***b) In this case (device1) can see only mac of (ISP router), not of (device 2)***

```
(device1) <-----> (ISP router) <-----> (device2)
```

**So based on macs you can configure who can connect to your wifi point, because it's about local network and direct connections.**

**But you have no ideas about macs of devices trying to come to your network from a remote location, in such scenarios knowing that remote devices macs is useless.**

Does it make sense?

Comment: Then, according to you, there is no way to protect ssh connections in layer 2

Comment: @ajcg You can protect ssh connections in a layer 2 network. All you have to do is extend your layer 2 network out to the remote hosts then add in your nat rules.

Comment: Each task has some appropriate tools. 
In your case, to limit ssh access to internal network/server, I probably would look into vpn and allow ssh only through vpn.

Comment: Another easier way may be to disable password authentication and use openssh keys instead, which would let you to log in, but makes brute force attacks against the openssh server useless (if that's the goal).

Comment: I understand your explanation, and it is reasonable. However it departs from the purpose of the question

Answer (score 0):

You can not see your real client mac on your server. There you see only gateway (router, etc) mac. You must read something about networks and protocols.

Comment: thanks for your advice. Maybe I should do it. But I will wait for a better answer to my question

Comment: It is impossible to do this validation

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to OPs question.

Comment: I think that "you can't do that" is a good answer in this case.